# C++ library project architecture

Tags: c++, class, header, project

I'm relatively new to C++, and I do not find useful info on the web about good project structure and architecture practices.

In a C++ project, I want to have an `#include "mylib"` in a main.cpp file and have access to its many classes (like when we include "iostream" or "math"). But I don't know the best practices according to C++ project management on how to do this.

Typically I'd create the mylib.h header file and have many classes within that file such that when I include "mylib.h" I can do `Class1 obj1;` and `Class2 obj2;` immediately. The structure would look like:

```
/
..src/
....main.cpp // call #include"mylib.h"
..inc/
....mylib.h // Class1.h, Class2.h defined here
```

But I've read that having many classes per file's not a good practice in C++. So I also wondered if it'd make sense to have a "mylib" directory instead of a header file, and the many class files inside of it. Like so

```
/
..src/
....main.cpp // call #include"mylib/Class1.h" and also #include"mylib/Class2.h"
..inc/
....mylib/
......Class1.h
......Class2.h
```

But some problems arise, like: calling some classes would force me to `#include "mylib/Class1.h"` and also "mylib/Class2.h"`, which I don't think it's very practical (repeating of mylib/*). I'm also not quite sure where to put the .cpp files corresponding to the .h files - in the same "mylib" directory or in the src directory?

So my question comes down to: should I create a folder "mylib" inside "inc", or should I create many classes within the "mylib.h" file, or is there another way that I am not considering? What is the best and common practice to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can split the difference. Within mylib, you can have mylib/Class1.h, mylib/Class2.h, etc. And then you can also have a file mylib/include.h, whose contents are just `#include "mylib/Class1.h"`, `#include "mylib/Class2.h"`, etc. Then you can include that single file, and it will transitively bring in all the individual classes.

Comment: @NathanPierson that's in fact an awesome idea. Is that technique typically used in open source?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that a lot.

Comment: You can also just look on many github projects. There you can see how many people do it.. They often do it the right way.

Comment: e.g. see boost: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio.hpp though in the case of boost its often a good idea to only include what you use to improve compile times

Comment: I recommend the [Pitchfork Layout](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork) as a good strategy to consider.

Answer (score 1):

This whole subject is obviously on the edge of the subjectivity cliff, but there are some principles that should be uncontroversial.  You do need to have a project-named **directory** for the same reason you need a project-named namespace: it dramatically reduces the number of identifiers that [might collide quadratically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox).  (You could use a distinguishing prefix with a delimiter other than `/` just like C does with symbols with a delimiter other than `::`, but that’s no improvement.)  Whether that lives in a directory named `inc` (or whatever else) or is colocated with the (library’s) source is a matter of style.

As for *public* headers, their number should be determined not by how many classes they contain but by how you want your clients to **understand** the structure of the library.  If that means that each such header merely `#include`s several internal header files (of a number that you choose based on private engineering concerns, whether or not based on a count of classes), so be it.